# libgdx background delay no freeze

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a few problems with time in my game. Play my game ([link](http://www.file-upload.net/download-8728102/SquishyBird.zip.html) won't post all code) to 50 points ... the tubes stay closed .. why?

The tubes only open in the game if a bird spawns, why?  The tubes are actually only 1 sec to be getting, do I have something wrong in the code?

The file in which I place the most important is code: `SquishyBird/SquishyBird/src/com/CoreTek/squishybird/GameScreen.java`

Seondly,
 how can I set a Delay when you touched at the background: `touched -> door close -> 1sec -> door opens`

Wwhile this `1 sec` the emenies at my game should still move, so it cant be a freeze delay. How can I do this?

Maybe the error is here:

```
    delayTime = TimeUtils.millis();

    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
        Assets.rect_pipe_down.y = 512 - 320/2 - 96;
        Assets.rect_pipe_up.y = -320 + 320/2 + 96;
        Assets.rect_hitbox.x = 288/2 - 52/2 + 2;            
    }

    if(TimeUtils.millis() - delayTime > 1000){
        Assets.rect_pipe_down.y = 512 - 320/2;
        Assets.rect_pipe_up.y = -320 + 320/2;
        Assets.rect_hitbox.x = 288/2 - 52/2 + 2 + 500;  
    }
```

My whole rendering:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta){
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0F, 0F, 0F, 1F);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();

    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    Assets.region_current_bird = Assets.animation_bird.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();
        batch.draw(Assets.region_bg, 0, 0);
        batch.draw(Assets.region_pipe_down, Assets.rect_pipe_down.x, Assets.rect_pipe_down.y);
        batch.draw(Assets.region_pipe_up, Assets.rect_pipe_up.x, Assets.rect_pipe_up.y);
        Assets.font_points.draw(batch, "Points: " + String.valueOf(points), 10, 512 - 10);
        for(Rectangle rect_bird: Assets.rect_birds_array){
            batch.draw(Assets.region_current_bird, rect_bird.x, rect_bird.y);
        }
    batch.end();

    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
        Assets.rect_pipe_down.y = 512 - 320/2 - 96;
        Assets.rect_pipe_up.y = -320 + 320/2 + 96;
        Assets.rect_hitbox.x = 288/2 - 52/2 + 2;            
    }

    if(TimeUtils.millis() - delayTime > 1000){
        Assets.rect_pipe_down.y = 512 - 320/2;
        Assets.rect_pipe_up.y = -320 + 320/2;
        Assets.rect_hitbox.x = 288/2 - 52/2 + 2 + 500;  
    }

    if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastSpawnTime > spawnTime) spawnBirds();

    Iterator<Rectangle> iter = Assets.rect_birds_array.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        Rectangle bird = iter.next();
        bird.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(bird.x - 34 > 288) iter.remove();
        if(bird.overlaps(Assets.rect_hitbox)){
            points++;
            if(spawnTime > 10){
                spawnTime-=10;
            }
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your "question" is not understandable. 5 of 7 people thought so so far...

Comment: You have to give us more informations. Out of your question, I don't understand what you problem is. Tell us what you want to achieve and what you have allready tryed.